# Unable to Use Variable as default_value in Clap with Lifetime Issue

Tags: rust, clap

I'm working on a Rust project where I'm using the Clap library to handle command-line arguments. I have a scenario where I want to set the default_value of a command-line argument based on a value calculated at runtime, but I'm encountering a lifetime issue.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
 let default_threads_name =  (num_cpus::get().saturating_sub(2).max(1)).to_string();

   let matches = Command::new("test")
    .version("1.0")
    .subcommand_required(true)
    .about("uploader")
    .arg(
        Arg::new("threadsHash")
            .long("threadsHash")
            .value_name("THREADS_HASH")
            .default_value(&*default_threads_name)
            .help("Number of threads for hashing"),
    )
    .get_matches();
```

The get_default_threads_name function calculates a value at runtime, and I want to use this value as the default_value for the "threadsHash" argument.

However, I'm encountering a lifetime issue because the borrowed value **(default_threads_name)** will expire by the time **get_matches()** returns the value. As a result, I'm unable to use the parsed arguments effectively.

Is there a way to work around this issue and set the default_value based on a runtime-calculated value without running into lifetime problems?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `default_threads_name` itself and not a reference to it:

```rust
let matches = Command::new("test")
    .version("1.0")
    .subcommand_required(true)
    .about("uploader")
    .arg(
        Arg::new("threadsHash")
            .long("threadsHash")
            .value_name("THREADS_HASH")
            .default_value(default_threads_name)
            .help("Number of threads for hashing"),
    )
    .get_matches();
```

You need to enable the `string` feature of `clap` as well.

Comment: I tried that but I received error the trait `From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `clap::builder::OsStr`

Comment: @florinstaicu Well [it works fine for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c55ed6d46180c34b13c687999457c5b7).

Comment: It's strange because when i used clap version "2.30.3" it works but on clap version "4.4.3" not working.

Comment: @florinstaicu Figured it out: it requires the `string` feature. Edited the answer.